# Creating a sidebar using reactjs and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a react project in which I need bootstrap sidebar which looks one of metronics https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic/demo1/index.html theme. I tried hard but couldn't copy it as I am not master of CSS.I need sidebar same as metronics. How could I make sidebar with the rotating caret and icons.

I have tried react-bootstrap but couldn't make it. Do i need to add custom css?

Thanks in advance

My sidebar component :

```
function SideBar(){
    return(
      
        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark align-items-start sidebar sidebar-dark accordion bg-gradient-primary p-0">
         <div className="container-fluid d-flex flex-column p-0">
         <Link className="navbar-brand d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center sidebar-brand m-0" href="#">
                <div className="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15"></div>
                <div className="sidebar-brand-text mx-3"><span>ProjectName </span>
               
                </div>
                <Button  className="rounded-circle border-0" ></Button>
            </Link>
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav text-light">
                <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/index">
                             <FaIcons.FaTachometerAlt/>
                             <span>Dashboard</span>
                        </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/profile">
                             <FaIcons.FaUser/>
                             <span>Profile</span>
                        </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/table">
                             <FaIcons.FaTable/>
                             <span>Table</span>
                        </Link>
                </li>
               
           
        </ul>
             </div>
        </nav>
       
    )
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? Please share your code.

Comment: Have you added any css to it?

Comment: See some examples here: https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar